# How can you make beanstalk app pull from github?

Tags: github, circleci

Is it possible to have beanstalk app pull from github? If so How?

We are using Circle CI for continuous integration but we use beanstalk app for server deployment.

Ideal workflow:

1. Push to github
2. Have circle ci pull from git and run tests
3. If tests pass, use a hook in beanstalk app to tell it to do a pull from
   github
4. Beanstalk app autodeploys to server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do that, but you should be able to do the push from CircleCI to BeanStalk. Would that work?

Comment: Yea, I think so. Probably the best workable solution. So the revised strategy should look like:

1. Push to github
2. Have circle CI pull from github and run tests
3. If tests pass, push to beanstalk using git
4. Beanstalk app autodeploys to server

Comment: I always think of Beanstalk as a "means to get code to a server under a deployment strategy". It can feels weird pushing from local to BSApp, but in a certain mindset it makes sense. Remember - you can run additional scripts on deployment (per server) the in theory allow pulls/clones/you flavor of weird.